# android code failed in socketing through wifi

Tags: java, android, sockets, wifi

I just wrote an app to connect to the wifi as follows:

```
wifi.setWifiEnabled(false);
wifi.setWifiEnabled(true);

int res = wifi.addNetwork(wificonfigurationA);              
boolean b = false;
b = wifi.enableNetwork(res, true);
Log.d("WifiPreference", "enableNetwork returned " + b);

Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, 3000);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

out.println("Hey Server!");
```

This gives the `01-02 00:03:36.882: E/ClientActivity(1550): java.net.ConnectException: /10.10.2.200:3000 - Network is unreachable` error. please help

Answer (score 0):

use connectionManagaer object to perform this operation and always do this type of network operation in separate thread.